# An animation in Angular to switch rows in a table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation, angular-animations

I have an HTML file that displays a voting chart for musical songs using Angular. Each time I press the refresh button, the chart data is updated by making a GET request. I am trying to create an animation that shows the changes in the table when the data is updated. For example, when the third most voted track becomes the first most voted track after the update, I want the third row to visually move up in the table and the first and second rows to move down. Can someone help me figure out how to achieve this animation?

```
   <button onclick="reloadData()">REFRESH</button>
   <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Rank</th>
         <th>Track</th>
         <th>Artist</th>
         <th>Percentage</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let track of votedTracks; let i = index">
         <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
         <td class="track-name">{{ track.name }}</td>
         <td class="artist-name">{{ track.artist }}</td>
         <td class="percentage">{{ track.percentage | number : "1.0-2" }}%</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

I have tried to create a custom animation using the Angular animation module, but the rows are not moving as expected. I'm expecting the rows to move up or down in the table when the data is updated and the ranking of the tracks changes. Last time it showed only the first row and than it gave me the error:

```
> ERROR Error: Unexpected synthetic property @moveRow found. Please make sure that:
> Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
> There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@moveRow` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your `app.module.ts` file.

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

You also need to add `[@moveRow]` to the `<tr>`, like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let track of votedTracks; let i = index" [@moveRow]>
```

All together it would something like this:

```js
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('moveRow', [
      state('in', style({transform: 'translateY(0)'})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}),
        animate(200)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(200, style({transform: 'translateY(100%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ],
  // ... etc
})
```

```js
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let track of votedTracks; let i = index" [@moveRow]="i">
    <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    <td class="track-name">{{ track.name }}</td>
    <td class="artist-name">{{ track.artist }}</td>
    <td class="percentage">{{ track.percentage | number : "1.0-2" }}%</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then in your `reloadData()` method you need to use ngZone.run() method because the change detection doesn't run automatically from an async data source... you would have something like this:

```js
reloadData() {
  this.http.get('/api/voted-tracks').subscribe(data => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.votedTracks = data;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see an animation now, but it's not the animation I wanted. Here is my code in the component.ts file : `[
    trigger('moveRow', [
      state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
        animate(200)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(200, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]`

Comment: `translateX` is horizontal movement